# Define function as interpolation of x,y data

Tags: matlab, function, spatial-interpolation

I have 2 columns of x y data in data.txt like this:

```
0  0
1  1
2  4
3  9
4  16
5  25
```

Now I want to define a function f(x) where x is the first column and f(x) is the second column, and then be able to print values of this function like so:

```
f(2)
```

Which should give me 4.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you want some return value for numbers between the ones you have as reference, you can use linear interpolation:

```
    function y= linearLut(x)
         xl = [0 1 2 3 4 5];
         yl = [0 1 4 9 16 25];
         y = interp1(xl,yl,x);
    end
```

A more generic version of the function might be:

```
    function y= linearLut(xl,yl,x)
         y = interp1(xl,yl,x);
    end
```

And then you can create specific instances by using anonymous functions:

```
    f = @(x)(linearLut([0 1 2 3 4],[0 1 4 9 16],x));
    f(4);
```

Comment: The top one is the sort of thing I want, however it gives me an error when I try it: 
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in interp (line 44)
if l < 1 || r < 1 || cutoff <= 0 || cutoff > 1

Error in test2>linearlut (line 10)
  y = interp(xl,yl,x);

Error in test2 (line 3)
linearlut(1)

Comment: Aha, fixed it by replacing 'interp' with 'interp1'. Update the answer and I will mark it accepted, thanks

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I was too hasty with my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can import the file using `textread()`, then use `find` in order to select the right row.

Out of my head and untested:

```
function y = findinfile(x)
    m = textread(data.txt)
    ind = find(m(:,1)==x)
    y = m(ind,2)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to find the correct value in the array (without interpolation) you can use:

```
function out=ff(b)
  a = [0 1 2 3 4 5 ; 3 4 5 6 7 8]';
  [c,d]=find(a(:,1)==b);
  out = a(c,2);
```