# Integration inside a triangle

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a matlab command that integrates a known function inside a triangle (which is known by his nodes).

I have 3 coordinates (x1,y1) (x2,y2) (x3,y3) that define a triangle and I know that inside the triangle there exist a **known** function f(x,y). I'm looking for a command that computes the integral of f over the triangle.

Comment: could you please provide some code of what you tried already and the data points

Comment: I added more information to the origin question. since im looking for a command there is no code, but the idea is very simple. i hope that u can help me

Comment: try `triquad` for numerical integration (not a built in, you can easily find on the google)

Comment: can u please share a link?

Answer (score 0):

Use `integral2` command in Matlab. The first example in the [Documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) will cover your case. To get one side of your triangle parallel to the x-axis you can multiply your triangle with a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and then "move" it on the x-axis.

Note that the integral is not influenced this transformations if your perform your [substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) correctly.
This transformations can make it easier to write your code but they're not necessary to use `integral2`.

Comment: Well, i also need to update F function as well, can u please write it ? suppose that three coordinates are given and also F in a known function.

Comment: F is a function recived from interuplated data. It's not analytic like F(x,y)=x or so.

Comment: If your data is interpolated you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559025/define-function-as-interpolation-of-x-y-data and then set the handle into `integral2`.